# What is the best event to bind dynamic controls in gridview or prevent the RowCreated Event EveryTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, where I'm creating column templates dynamically as

```
public void DynamicColumnsToGridView()
 {
     foreach (Employees emp in EmployeesList)
     {
         TemplateField gvTemplate = new TemplateField();
         gvTemplate.HeaderText = emp.Qualification;
         gvEmplys.Columns.Add(gvTemplate);
     }
 }
```

I'm calling DynamicColumnsToGridView() and binding the gridview in `!Page.IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DynamicColumnsToGridView();
        BindGridview();
    }
 }
```

I'm creating the controls dynamically in `RowCreated` event as

```
protected void gvEmplys_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}
```

In the `RowCreated` event I'm generating controls like `Buttons` etc.

The problem is that after generating the controls whenever I fire the `events` of those `controls` it is again firing the `RowCreated` event and then fires that `particular event`

Due to this the controls are again `re-genrated` which gets the performance issues. How can I prevent `RowCreated` being fired everytime or is there anyother events that can do without getting this problem

Comment: Its been a few years since I've ASP.NET'd but, could you perhaps use the `RowDataBound` event to generate your inner controls, instead? I believe that one will only fire once, since you are not binding every postback.

Comment: @DanS As I'm binding gridview if the `!Page.IsPostBack` the `RowDataBound ` doesn't even showing the controls